# Coger correctamente los datos en js

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

estoy practicando en js con un ejercicio en el cual mi idea es crear un botón en el cual dependiendo de si escribo en el input p1 o p2 a la hora de darle al botón de agrandar me agrande el párrafo con el id p1 o el del p2 hasta un máximo de tamaño, tengo el código escrito pero creo que me falla a la hora de coger el valor que introduzco al input y por eso no lo hace. ¿Alguna ayuda? Adjunto parte del codigo html y js.

```js
function agrandar(value){
    let value = document.getElementById("input").value;
    let parrafo1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    let parrafo2 = document.getElementById("p1");
    if (value=== parrafo1){
        if(parrafo1.style.fontSize == 2) {
            alert("No puedo hacerte la letra más grande");
            return;
        }
        else {
            parrafo1.style.fontSize = fontSize+0.5;
        }
    }

    if (value==parrafo2){
        if(parrafo2.style.fontSize == 2) {
            alert("No puedo hacerte la letra más grande");
            return;
        }
        else {
            parrafo2.style.fontSize = fontSize+0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Mi nombre es Starnix <strong>id = p1</strong></p>
    <p id="p2">Este es el segundo parrafo <strong>id = p2</strong></p>
    <input type="text" name="" id="input">
    <button onclick="agrandar();"> Agrandar</button>
```

Comment: ¿Hay restricciones en tu *ejercicio* ? Es decir, ¿te han dicho *debes usar esta cosa o la otra y no puedes usar tal cosa* ? Pregunto porque esto es muy sencillo aplicando métodos adecuados.

Comment: Por otra parte, el código no es claro, ¿qué es lo que quieres determinar en los  `if`? ¿Estás usando `.css` en los elementos, si es así, agrega el `.css` en cuestión.

Comment: Tu código tiene un problema, y es que no partes de ningun font-size en los párrafos, por lo tanto tocará calcular el font-size por defecto del navegador, tal como enseñan [en este enlace](https://brokul.dev/detecting-the-default-browser-font-size-in-javascript) primero, y se riguroso con la unidad usada (px, rem, etc) pues va a influir en la respuesta.  No creo que quieras complicarlo tanto, así que modifica tu pregunta agregando un font-size en dichos párrafos para que podamos darte una buena respuesta, gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano No hay ninguna restricción en mi ejercicio, respecto al CSS no estoy aplicándolo en ningún otro lugar, solo aquí, no tengo una hoja de estilos creada a parte.

Comment: @masterguru Probé también indicándole un font-size a los párrafos como em o px, me funcionaba pero solo cuando hago la primera vez click me lo cambia a determinado tamaño y luego si vuelvo a pulsar no lo va sumando y vuelve a cambiar, aún así creo que ya lo solucioné, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin cambiar la idea que quieres aplicar, he corregido unos cuantos fallos que tenías:

- No estabas usando el parámetro value para nada, así que lo he quitado.
- Una vez que obtienes el valor del input, puedes usarlo para obtener el párrafo, no necesitas duplicar código.
- El valor de fontSize es `""` porque no está explícitamente puesto en el elemento (no tiene atributo `style="..."`), así que obtengo el calculado por el navegador con [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Además, el valor **necesita** una unidad, así que no es un número sino un string. Por tanto uso `parseFloat` para quedarme con el número y poder aumentarlo.
  Añado 1 en cada ejecución, no sé si tu 2 hacía referencia a `2em` pero el valor que obtenemos es en *CSS pixels*.

No he arreglado el error que ocurre si introduces un valor incorrecto en el input

```js
function agrandar(){
  let value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let parrafo = document.getElementById(value);
  console.log('Valor actual', getComputedStyle(parrafo).fontSize);
  let fontSize=parseFloat(getComputedStyle(parrafo).fontSize)
  if(fontSize >= 20) {
    alert("No puedo hacerte la letra más grande");
  } else {
    parrafo.style.fontSize = (fontSize+1) +'px';
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Mi nombre es Starnix <strong>id = p1</strong></p>
<p id="p2">Este es el segundo parrafo <strong>id = p2</strong></p>
<input type="text" name="" id="input">
<button onclick="agrandar();"> Agrandar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé si se agrega aquí o en comentarios

Con esta validación controlas si hubo una entrada incorrecta en el input @Pablo Lozano, @starnix

```
  function agrandar(){
    let value = document.getElementById("input").value;
    let parrafo = document.getElementById(value);
    
    if (parrafo) {
       console.log('Valor actual', getComputedStyle(parrafo).fontSize);
       let fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(parrafo).fontSize)

          if (fontSize >= 20) {
             alert("No puedo hacerte la letra más grande");
          }else{
             parrafo.style.fontSize = (fontSize+1) +'px';
          }

    }else{
      alert('ID incorrecto')
      //console.log('Ese ID no existe')
    }
  }
```